# ComboBox returning System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, combobox

My C# code is as follows

```
    private void offHwyManufacturer_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var offHwyManufacturerSelected = offHwyManufacturerComboBox.SelectedValue;
        var query = "SELECT DISTINCT [EQUIPMENT TYPE] FROM ApplicationOffHwyData WHERE MANUFACTURER = '" + offHwyManufacturerSelected + "' ORDER BY [EQUIPMENT TYPE]";
        using (var adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, ConnString))
        {
            var offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable = new DataTable();
            adaptor.Fill(offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable);

            offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "[EQUIPMENT TYPE]";
            offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "[EQUIPMENT TYPE]";
            offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DataSource = offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable;
        }
    }
```

offHwyManufacturerComboBox is the first combobox, and this fires the 'SelectedValueChanged' event (This displays elements correctly)

However, on the second dropdown list (Equipment Type)  I'm getting System.Data.DataRowView instead of the actual value.

I'm well aware that I need to assign a DisplayMember / ValueMember, which I have done, yet it still isnt giving the right result.

If I run that SQL command manually (using the first option from 'Manufacturer' as an example) this is the result

```
EQUIPMENT TYPE
Compactors
Crawler Tractors
Dozers
Drilling Equipment
Excavators
Farm Equipment
Forestry Equipment
Generators, Gen Set Engines
Hydraulic Controls
Industrial Engines
Integrated Toolcarriers
Lift Trucks
Loaders
Marine Engines
Marine Gear
Material Handlers
Motor Graders
Off-Highway Trucks
Paving Equipment
Pipelayers
Scrapers, Wheel Tractors
Telehandlers
Turbine Engines
Winches
Windrow Elevators
```

Obviously this is only returning one row anyway, and the column name is 'EQUIPMENT TYPE'

Here is a screenshot of my WinForm app.

[image]

Am I just dense, or am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Please specify Winform, WPF ?

Comment: WinForm, correct. Apologies

Comment: Just remove your brackets from the DisplayMember and ValueMember declarations.  Better learn to use parameters for your queries to avoid sql injection, and better learn that quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things that seem odd are a) using an alphanumeric field for both `DisplayMember` and `Value Member`and b) a space in the field name (even though  you have enclosed [EQUIPMENT TYPE] in brackets).

So 1st suggestion is to fix both those potential issues like this:

```
var query = "SELECT DISTINCT Id, [EQUIPMENT TYPE] AS EquipmentType FROM ApplicationOffHwyData WHERE MANUFACTURER = '" + offHwyManufacturerSelected + "' ORDER BY [EQUIPMENT TYPE]";
using (var adaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, ConnString))
{
    var offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable = new DataTable();
    adaptor.Fill(offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable);

    offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "EquipmentType";
    offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
    offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DataSource = offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable;
}
```

The 2nd suggestion  is to to use a BindingSource with its `DataSource = offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable`, then set the combobox's DataSource to the BindingSource with its `DisplayMember` set to value and `Value Member` set to key. Here is rough outline of what that would look like:

```
BindingSource bs;
...
var offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable = new DataTable();
adaptor.Fill(offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable);

bs.DataSource = offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable;
offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "EquipmentType";
offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, appreciate your quick reply. Can you illustrate how I would adapt my code? Sorry, I'm a little slow, but I can't quite follow your answer. I've done this, but it's giving the same response `                offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DisplayMember = "value";
                offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.ValueMember = "key";
                offHwyEquipmentTypeComboBox.DataSource = offHwyEquipmentTypeDataTable;`

Comment: See my edit and try my first suggestion while I type up the code for the second suggestion

Comment: Your database table  **ApplicationOffHwyData** should have a PrimaryKey column, I guessed it was called `Id`.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, your first solution worked, by removing the 'ID' select statement and the `ValueMember` line